# Perl system call without path to executable, except using PATH variable

Tags: perl, include, system-calls

I don't know how to google this right: I want to call an external tool in `Perl` - For non root installed modules I can add the directory to `@INC`. But this don't work for other binaries/executables. E.g. Perlfile is in `/home/user/dev/perl.pl`, Modules are in `/home/user/dev/modules/`, Pythonscript is in `/home/user/dev/tools/python.py`. Now I can `push @INC,'/home/user/dev/modules/'` to find all modules. For the pythonscript I need to use the whole path `system("python /home/user/dev/tools/python.py")`. Is there a possibility to search the tools directory automatically, without adding it to build PATH, so I only need to call `system("python python.py")`? Thx

Comment: the python script is only an example. I call several tools, written in java, c++ and python and it would be nice, if I only need to set the tools root directory somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your update,

> Setting $ENV in perl.pl has no affect. $export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/dev/tools and running $python.py from shell works.

That's not true. If that works, so does setting the `$ENV{PATH}` and running `python.py` from Perl.

```
local $ENV{PATH} = "$ENV{PATH}:/home/user/dev/tools";
system("python.py");
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. After trying some things I know now why it didn't run. I worked on a module and not a script. So good to know one can't set environment variables in modules...

Comment: The program must be executable ("x" mode) and must be an executable (proper shebang line). But that's the case from the shell and from Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the path to the PATH variable from within the Perl script:

```
$ENV{PATH} .= ':/home/user/dev/tools';
```

As usually, the setting cannot change the PATH variable of the parent process, only the script itself and its children processes.

Comment: @pyr0: Each user can set his/her own PATH.

Comment: mh using `ENV` this results furthermore in `Can't exec "Bcheck": No such file or directory at` ...

Comment: @pyr0: `python` probably does not search PATH for scripts to run (try in the command line).

Comment: @pyr0: if the python script is executable, you can run it by setting PATH and then plain `system 'python.py';`.

Comment: adding the path to build PATH and executing the script is no problem

Answer (score 0):

If your Python scripts have correct shebang line (e.g. `#!` first line) pointing to python, you do NOT need to do `system("python /home/user/dev/tools/python.py")` - merely `system("/home/user/dev/tools/python.py")` is enough.

Then you don't need to rely on Python searching `$PATH`.

Then, you can then change your $PATH:

```
local $ENV{PATH} = $ENV{PATH} ? "$ENV{PATH}:/home/user/dev/tools" 
                              : "/home/user/dev/tools";

system("python.py");
```

(Make sure to localize this so as to not affect the PATH elsewhere in your program)

Comment: @pyr0 - see the final version of the answer.

Comment: @pyr0: are you still doing `python python.py`?

Comment: you may need to `chmod a+x python.py`

Comment: no, actual I call `system("python.py")`. $`export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/dev/tools` and running $`python.py` works

Comment: Try `use IPC::System::Simple 'system';   ... system('python.py');` to get decent error reporting from system.

Comment: I am sorry for the circumstances, but IPC modules are not installed by our admin (Can't locate IPC ... in @INC)

Comment: then try `my $return = system('python.py'); print "system got: $return, $?, $! " . (0+$!) . "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach that may or may not fit your needs:

Somewhere before calling system:

```
chdir '/home/user/dev/tools' or die "Couldn't chdir to tools: $!\n";
```